# Navbar dropdowns stop working when added a modal

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Here I am facing a strange issue after calling a modal form, the navbar dropdowns stop working.

Any clue?

here is the link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-stonebraker-hfcln?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

To reproduce the issue:
from Navbar go to Master data > customers > the modal form will open > close the modal form > then go back to the menu and they to open the master data drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Use react router's Link to navigate:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

In MainNav component:

```
<Link to="/customers">
  <NavDropdown.Item >Customers</NavDropdown.Item>
</Link>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bash-tkhn8?file=/src/mainnav.jsx

Href redirects the page to a particular location(Page redirects, state of the app is lost). Link from react-router-dom allows you to navigate to different routes with the page loading retaining state of your react app (internal routing).

Comment: Could you please elaborate the why?

Comment: I agree on your statement but a the same time we are rendering two links because I see this Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.

Comment: Your explanation actually helped me get to the right solution so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

Basically we need to convert the Navbar.Item to Link that's how you can avoid nesting to anchors. My code look like this now:
`<NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/customers">Customers</NavDropdown.Item>`